# Why won't the following operations work in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scientific-notation, operation

If input into a Matlab script, the following are deemed as unacceptable:

```
   i) 8.8*e-2  
   ii) 3.2e1.5 
   iii) 1.25e+005
```

But why doesn't i), ii) and iii) work? 
Is it because `e` is undefined?

I would have thought the reason for i) is because of the unnecessary `*`, but there is no `*` in either ii) or iii) and I believe they are also unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i:

```matlab
>> 8.8*e-2
Undefined function or variable 'e'.
```

This is self explanatory; you're asking to multiply with the `*` operator. It should be `8.8e-2`

---

ii:

```matlab
 >> 3e1.5
 3e1.5
    ↑
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

From Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> Scientific notation (also referred to as scientific form or standard index form, or standard form in the UK) is a way of expressing numbers that are too big or too small to be conveniently written in decimal form. [...]
>
> In scientific notation, all numbers are written in the form `m × 10^n`
>   (m times ten raised to the power of n), **where the exponent n is an integer**, and the coefficient m is any real number.

You want to use

```matlab
>> 3*10^1.5
ans =
   94.8683
```

---

iii:

```matlab
>> 1.25e+005
ans =
      125000
```

What's the problem?

---

> 2 ARE acceptable: 6,10 and .0

Can you clarify this question? It doesn't seem to be about scientific notation.

```matlab
>> 6,10
ans =
     6
ans =
    10
>> .0
ans =
     0
```